# How to communicate between spring boot and nodejs app in same network without login for specifc endpoint

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, nginx, heroku

I need help to find way to communicate http call between internal application (backend spring boot) and another application (nodejs) without login, authentification...

**Here is the details of my heroku environment :**

- A front end application in angular 5
- A back end application in spring boot
- Another back end application in nodejs

The front end app need to call the spring boot app and this one should call nodejs app.

**Front end App => Spring boot app => Nodejs App**

The Nodejs app route endpoint called by spring boot app must be securized, this one must not be open from outside the network heroku environment.

The Nodejs app contain many other routes securized by google authentification account. However i don't want add google authentification for specfic route used by spring boot (because this route must not be access from outside the heroku network from 'normal user').

How should i do ?
Could i install and configure nginx to disallow route access from outside but only allow from the heroku network ?

Thank you for help.